# why does my smtp does not work when I am hosting my website in hostgator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a submit form in my website. When I run my code in my localhost it works. In there I am using smtp.gmail.com with port 587. When I upload my website on line it does not submit my form it gives me an error message. In control panel in hostgator is Plesk. Does any body has any suggestion on what I can do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a relay?

In other words, is the email provider the same one as the web hosting? Many (if not most) web sites OFTEN prevent sending of emails from any other location then the web hosting.

The reason for this is "many". So, this means hackers etc. then can't hack the web site, and use that web providers web site for sending emails on THEIR behalf!.

In other words, firewall and other features will not allow sending of a email from any other location or email provider except those from that given provider (in this case the web hosting email system).

I would create a test email account on the web hosting provider, and try that.

If this is a company email you are trying to use and NOT one from the hosting provider? Then your IT folks can often setup a "relay" rule to allow this, but this is not a surprise, since most web hosting systems block use of emails from anyone other then emails made for the given hosting plan.

Probably best is to go to the web hosting panel, create a user, and the check the documentation for what port etc. to use. So, "internal" code behind the web site firewalls can send emails, but any email system outside of the web hosting system often cannot be used for reason of security and hacking.

You have to check with your hosting provider - they may well not allow 3rd party emails such as gmail or whatever to be used.